# Unnamed object literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The below code is perfectly valid in JavaScript :-

> `( { a:10 , b:20 , c:30 } );`

But when do we need such an Object which we can't reference in our code ?

Comment: We don't. But then `"no point to this string";` is valid JS too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You often use an unnamed literal as a parameter to a function call. A popular example is calling jQuery plugin methods on elements, eg:

```
$("div").someMethod({prop:'value',otherProp:'value2'});
```

It is also possible (and often beneficial) to assign such objects to variables beforehand and then passing it in, like so:

```
var options = {prop:'value',otherProp:'value2'};
$("div").someMethod(options);
```

But sometimes its just easier and cleaner the first way.

Comment: What you've said is true, but it doesn't really address the question which talks about an object literal on a line by itself which can't be referenced from anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks Andy..Then how does the actual function (someMethod () )  work with this object literal we have passed ?

Comment: @nnnnnn I understand, but i figured perhaps he was asking when one would use an unnamed literal. @RohitP, `someMethod` would look like this:
    someMethod = function(myObject){
        // then use properties
        console.log(myObject.prop,myObject.otherProp);
    }

Comment: Hey Andy..Thanks..looks neat!!!

Answer (score 2):

`( { a:10 , b:20 , c:30 } );` has no use as you don't have reference of the object. but same way we can define anonymous function `(function(){  })()`; which is very useful.

Comment: An anonymous function is only useful if it might be called. An uncalled anonymous function is as useful as an uncalled declared function (i.e. it isn't).

Comment: @RobG - Yes, but Shusl's example was an immediately invoked anonymous function, so (assuming it had actual content) that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This code is a bit 'pointless' as you can't reference it (as you've said).

You can construct valid code in many languages that 'does nothing'.

For example,

```
function foo() {
    var bar = 42;
}
```

Again, the above function is perfectly valid, but doesn't do much.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this can be pretty handy. E.g. you can perfectly handle I18n with that approach:

```
({de: {title: 'foo'}, en: {title: 'bar'}})[navigator.language.slice(0,2)]
```

So you could end up with smth like this:

```
var lang = navigator.language.slice(0,2)
var dict = ({de: {title: 'foo'}, en: {title: 'bar'}})[lang]
console.log(dict.title)
```

Comment: ahh..I see..That sounds cool...

Answer (score 1):

`()` is The Grouping Operator.
[[reference](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.6)]

This expression returns the result of evaluating.
This may be of type reference.

```
{a:10, b:20, c:30}['a'];   // invalid
({a:10, b:20, c:30})['a']; // valid. 
Because the object `{a:10, b:20, c:30}` is after being evaluated.
```

Comment: The parentheses are needed to force the object to be interpreted as an expression even though it appears on a line by itself, because otherwise the curly brackets `{}` are interpreted as a block. You don't need parentheses if the object appears where an expression is expected, e.g., `alert({a:10, b:20, c:30}['a']);` works fine, as does `+{a:10, b:20, c:30}['a'];`.

Comment: Thank you.
If you use the function `alert`, because `(` arrive before the `{',
Is recognized as an unnamed object.